# I am using laravel 5.8, and I cannot insert data to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, mamp

I am using laravel 5.8 and learning CRUD. I have 2 tables, users table and addresses table. I want to connect user_id to

addresses table. But my code doesn't work. I cannot insert data.

I have already migrate 2 tables, and I am able to add columns.
I inserted one user's data. So table has one user's information.

I am using MAMP and mysql server in local server.

1.App/Address.php

```
protected $fillable = [
     'name'
];//
```

2.App/User.php

```
public function address(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Address', 'foreign_key');
}
```

3.Userstable

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->Increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

4.Addresses table

```
Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->Increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->string('name');
        //$table->timestamps();
    });
```

5.routes/web.php

```
use App\User;
use App\Address;
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/insert', function(){
$user = User::findOrFail(1);
$address = new Addresses(['name'=>'1234 Houston av NY NY 234']);
$user->address()->save($address);
});
```

Nothing shows on log file, so I cannot figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: replace this address method with this code return $this->hasOne('App\Address', 'user_id');

Comment: checklist : 
1. make sure .env is configured with the correct database credentials
2. php artisan key:generate [key is generated]
3. mysql is running
4. php artisan serve (running)

Comment: `new Address(['name'=>'1234 Houston av NY NY 234']);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I add code for insert data into database step by step

Create migration for creating post table

```
php artisan make:migration create_post_table --create=post
```

Add title and content column in migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('post', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->longText('content');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

create post folder in the view directory 
in the post folder create blade file create.blade.php

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('post.store') }}">
    @csrf

   Title:  <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" required>

   <br>

    Content: <textarea name="content" placeholder="Content" required></textarea>

    <button type="submit">Save</button>

</form>
```

Create the controller

```
php artisan make:controller PostController --resource
```

code in controller

```
use App\Post;

    public function create()
    {
        return view('post.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'content' => 'required',
        ]);

        $post = $request->all();

        Post::create($post);

        return redirect('/post');
    }
```

In route file (web.php)

```
//routes for post
Route::resource('post', 'PostController');
```

Open the post form

```
http://example.test/post/create
```

enter title and content and click on save button

Comment: Sorry, still it doesn't work, and also according to your advice, is it little useless to learn CRUD like this way ? What do you think to skip or proceed this learning.

Comment: please check in the users table, User exists with ID 1 or not

Comment: I have change above code for insert data with full details step by step

Comment: @YoheiUmezu I have done above code for insert post title and content into database

Comment: Good morning. Thank you so much ! I will try those !

Comment: Good morning. Okay

Answer (score 1):

In your `Addresses` table,

```
Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->Increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->string('name');
        //$table->timestamps();

        // define foreign key like this
        $table->foreign('user_id')
              ->references('id')->on('users')
              ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

update your `routes/web.php` like below,

```
Route::get('/insert', function(){
    $user = User::findOrFail(1);
    $address = new Addresses();
    $address->name = '1234 Houston av NY NY 234';
    $address->user_id = $user->id;
    $address->save();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The relationship in your User Model is not valid. You should correct this to work with the relation.

2.App/User.php

```
public function address(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Address', 'user_id','id');
}
```

Another method to assign your address to the user (alternative way and just a hint):

```
$address = new Addresses(['name'=>'1234 Houston av NY NY 234', 'user_id',$user->id]);
$adresss->save();
```

I think you also should add the relation to your database migration. In your code you did not.

4.Addresses table

```
Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->Increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->string('name');

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('user'); // this line is the forgein key.
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but still it doesn't work.